# Pattern matching style in C++?

Tags: c++, macros, pattern-matching

I love Haskell style pattern matching.

I have my C++ code as follows:

```
ObjectPtr ptr;
if(ptr.isType<Foo>()) { // isType returns a bool
  Ptr<Foo> p = ptr.convertAs<Foo>(); // convertAs returns a Ptr<Foo>
  ......
}
if(ptr.isType<Bar>()) {
  Ptr<Bar> p = ptr.convertAs<Bar>();
  ......
}
```

Now, are there any macros I can do define to simplify this? I have been pondering this for a while, but can't simplify it further.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are missing `()` after `isType`.

Comment: In Mach7, your code will look as following:

<pre><code>
Match(*ptr) {
Case(Foo) return match0.foo_member();
Case(Bar) return match0.bar_member();
Otherwise() return 0;
} EndMatch
</code></pre>

See https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7 and my answer about Mach7 below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `Ptr` template has the concept of a NULL pointer.

```
ObjectPtr ptr;
if(Ptr<Foo> p = ptr.convertAs<Foo>()) { // convertAs returns a NULL pointer if the conversion can't be done.
  ......
}
if(Ptr<Bar> p = ptr.convertAs<Bar>()) {
  ......
}
```

Though, as others have noted, switching on type is usually a sign you're doing something wrong in C++.  You ought to consider using virtual functions instead.

Comment: Doesn't this just raise another question - "how to I write convertAs() to do that?"

Comment: @Neil:Not really -- his original code assumed the existence of a convertAs. This would presumably use a dynamic_cast, which produces a null pointer if it can't convert a pointer to the target type. As such, chances are pretty good that it's already present, or fairly easy to implement if not present.

Comment: The best part is, in C++0x you can replace `Ptr<Foo>` with `auto`.

Answer (score 7):

`dynamic_cast` would appear to do what you want

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : struct  A { ... };
struct C : struct  A { ... };

A * a = new C;

if ( C * c = dynamic_cast<C*>( a ) ) {
   c->someCfunc();
}
else if ( B * b = dynamic_cast<B*>( a ) ) {
   b->someBfunc();
}
else {
   throw "Don't know that type";
}
```

Comment: Then do a dynamic cast on the contained pointer - for example, if you are using std::auto_ptr(), do it on the result of calling get().

Answer (score 7):

> I love Haskell style pattern matching.

Then write your program in Haskell.

What you're trying to do is a switch over a type. That's a common thing people do if they want to avoid virtual functions. Now, the latter are a cornerstone of what OO in C++ is all about. If you want to avoid them, why do you program in C++?

---

As for why this is frowned upon: Imagine you have a lot of code like this

```
if(ptr.isType<Foo>()) ...
if(ptr.isType<Bar>()) ...
```

smeared all over your code and then someone comes and adds `Baz` to the possible types that `ptr` might represent. Now you're hunting through a big code base, trying to find all those places where you switched over a type, and trying to find out which ones you need to add `Baz` to.

And, as Murphy has it, just when your done, there comes along `Foz` to be added as a type, too. (Or, thinking again, if Murphy has his way it creeps in *before* you had a chance too complete adding `Baz`.)

Comment: Low level memory control of C. Constructors & Destructors of objects on the Stack <-- this is amazing, as it gives smart pointers, RAII, ...; standard template library (does any of this use virtual functions?). +1 assuming answer was genuine question, not troll.

Comment: It certainly wasn't a genuine question, but neither was it a troll. It was a rhetorical question. To be plain: _You shouldn't do this in C++_. That's what virtual functions were invented for; they put all the code relating to objects of the type `Foo` into `Foo` itself, and everything relating to `Baz` into `Baz`. This isn't always the best you can get (witness, for example, the motivation behind the visitor pattern), but it's the default you should start with in C++.

Comment: ``Now, the latter are a cornerstone of what OO in C++ is all about.`` Then why should we use template metaprogramming when it's basically FP and not OO at all, we should all go to Haskel instead of using the STL, boost or using our own templates... _rolleyes_ Furthermore only someone completelly ignorant of the C++ would make such a question, [like this guy (link to pdf)](http://www.stroustrup.com/OpenPatternMatching.pdf) totally clueless!

Comment: @Trinidad: While TMP is indeed FP, it is definitely not OO. I had a very cursory glance at that paper. Correct me if I'm wrong, but nothing I saw in it at a first glance advertises the classic and simple _switch over type_ the OP wants, so common in C, which just cries for polymorphism in C++. Now, I freely admit to know next to nothing about Haskell and that my exposure to LISP was very short and decades ago, so I might be completely off here, but I do know that what the OP wants is frowned upon in C++ for very good reasons. (I once inherited such code, and was tasked with `Baz` and `Foz`.)

Comment: @sbi Mach7 does the switch over type (which is only a tiny part of what is referred to as pattern matching) and other things. OOD provides very verbose alternatives to pattern matching (even the switch over type). Imagine creating a new virtual method and one implementation in every subclass for every ``case``, it's ugly, and all over the code, a maintenance pain and you need to create lots of methods and even sub-classes for accomplishing the same 1 single ``switch`` does. In this case using virtual methods you're not dealing with the solution at all. See (zip w/source): http://goo.gl/HNOKvo

Comment: @Trinidad: If you have many classes and are frequently adding algorithms, virtual functions are not well-suited. OOP invented the visitor pattern there, but I have no trouble believing you that other languages have other constructs for this and that they are superior in some, or even many, circumstances. I also had the impression that Mach7 can do lots of things, and that the ability to switch over types is just a byproduct of that. However, what the OP here wanted was a simple case you would solve with a type-tagging enum in C. For that, polymorphism is typically better in many (most?) cases.

Answer (score 5):

Attempting to simulate a pattern matching style in C++ using RTTI is a neat idea, but it's bound to have shortcomings, because there are some significant differences between Haskell and Standard ML style type constructors and C++ subclasses. (Note: below, I use Standard ML syntax because I'm more comfortable with it.)

- In Haskell and Standard ML, pattern matching can bind nested values to pattern variables for you (e.g. the pattern `a::b::c::ds` binds the first three elements of the list to `a`, `b`, and `c`, and the rest of the list to `ds`). In C++, you'll still have to dig around in the actual nested structures, unless you or someone else comes up with far more complicated macros than have been proposed here.
- In Haskell and Standard ML, a type constructor datatype declaration like `datatype 'a option = NONE | SOME of 'a` defines one new type: `'a option`. Constructors `NONE` and `SOME` are not types, they are values with types `'a option` and `'a -> 'a option`, respectively. In C++, when you define subclasses like `Foo` and `Bar` to simulate type constructors, you get new types.
- In Haskell and Standard ML, constructors like `SOME` are first-class functions that construct values of the datatype to which they belong. For example, `map SOME` has the type `'a list -> 'a option list`. In C++, using subclasses to simulate type constructors, you don't get this ability.
- In Haskell and Standard ML, datatypes are closed, so no one can add more type constructors without changing the original declaration, and the compiler can verify at compile time that the pattern match handles all cases. In C++, you have to go well out of your way to restrict who can subclass your base class.

In the end, are you getting enough benefit from simulated pattern matching compared to using C++ polymorphism in a more typical way? Is using macros to make simulated pattern matching slightly more concise (while obfuscating it for everyone else who reads your code) worthwhile?

Answer (score 4):

We co-authored a pattern matching library for C++ that allows you to do pattern matching and type analysis very efficiently. The library, called Mach7, has been released under BSD license and is available on GitHub: https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7. You can find videos, posters, slides, papers as well as the source code there. It currently supports GCC 4.4+, Clang 3.4+ and Visual C++ 2010+. Feel free to ask question's about the library by submitting a GitHub issue against its repository.

Answer (score 2):

A think this macro does precisely what you want:

```
#define DYN_IF(dest_type, dest_ptr, src_ptr)                                 \
    if((src_ptr).isType<dest_type>())                                        \
        if(int dest_type##dest_ptr = 1)                                      \
        for(Ptr<dest_type> dest_ptr = (src_ptr).convertAs<dest_type>();      \
            dest_type##dest_ptr;                                             \
            dest_type##dest_ptr=0)
```

Usage:

```
ObjectPtr ptr;
DYN_IF(Foo, foo_ptr, ptr) { 
    // foo_ptr is Ptr<Foo>
}
DYN_IF(Bar, bar_ptr, ptr)  // Works without braces too for single statement 
    // bar_ptr is Ptr<Bar>
```

I wouldn't recommend this sort of stuff in code that is meant to be read by somebody else, but since you mentioned the word "macro"...

Also, I wouldn't pretend this has anything to do with pattern matching in the Haskell/OCaml style. Check Scala if you want a language that has semantics similar to C++ (well, sort of) and true pattern matching.